# Is it okay to ask about other sites if the purpose is to know how sites work in general?

Tags: discussion

Like this question.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44781/how-do-some-sites-handle-copyright-issue?noredirect=1#comment44274_44781

I want to know how copyright works. I do not want to break the law. However, if something can be done reasonably legally or with few legal consequences, I don't want to be left behind.

It's easier to express my idea by showing how others are doing it. Some says that I have to ask about my sites. Well, my sites are not made yet. I want to know whether it's legal or not before making it.

What about if I want to make another site like that site and want to follow the same strategy?

Comment: Short of reading the legalese of the copyright laws in whatever country you're hosted in directly, I'm not sure how else "how copyright works" can be handled by the Faceless Internet Horde. This is also a subject not handled well by Stack Exchange *as a software* for reasons too numerous to articulate.

Answer (score 2):

A moderator should be able to give some insight to the reasons being but I personally believe that your question is off topic never mind not very constructive it's important to note while the most of us are experienced webmasters it doesn't mean we are necessary in the position to answer copyright, trademark and other infringing laws. You should be seeking the appropriate legal advice from professionals in this field (I.E Copyright Consultancy's and Lawyers).

In your question about how do other sites handle legal matters, it is one or more of 5 possibilities:

- They ignore copyright law.
- They seek professional legal advice.
- They obey copyright laws and seek appropriate permission before publishing.
- They purchase the rights to use the copyrighted material.
- They use some kind of open license that allows the material to be published on selected platforms under the licensing terms of the agreement (i.e creative commons).

Quite frankly its very inappropriate to seek legal advice from people who could give you the wrong advice and then you will be found liable.